# Unpack list of unknown number of references as target list in for loop

Tags: python-3.x

Here is what I am trying to do.

```
from itertools import product

li = []
# Append arbitrary/unknown number of integers to li

ranges = [range(1, n) for n in li]

# Question 1: How to create a list of *references* whose length is that of li (or ranges)
# Is this the right way?

target_list = [None, ] * len(ranges)

# Question 2: Unpack this target_list of references in a for-loop, How to?
# Something like so (of course this does not work, just trying to convey intent)

for *target_list in product(ranges):
    # Access specific elements of target_list
```

Please let me know if the intent of what I am doing is not clear or if I can word it better in any way.

Thank you for listening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out, I didn't need to create a target_list and "unpack" it in a for-loop.

To achieve what I wanted to do, all I had to do was unpack the argument to `product` like so:

```
from itertools import product

li = []
# Append arbitrary/unknown number of integers to li

ranges = [range(1, n) for n in li]

for target_list in product(*ranges): # Note ranges is unpacked
    # Access specific elements of target_list
```